# Compare variables in MySQL and save the result into other variable

Tags: mysql

I have `3 variables` in a loop.

Those variables are changing his value and I want to compare it and if a value is the same in the `3 variables`.

I want to save it into other variable and `insert into` a table.
I have it now, I just add many changes in the code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getFiltrado(pabellon INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE vcodigo1 INT;
DECLARE vcodigo2 INT;
DECLARE vcodigo3 INT;
DECLARE cursor12 CURSOR FOR SELECT codigo FROM TEMP3;
DECLARE cursor13 CURSOR FOR SELECT codigo FROM TEMP4;
DECLARE cursor14 CURSOR FOR SELECT codigo FROM TEMP5;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @fin=1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP6;
CREATE TABLE TEMP6(codigo INT);
SET @fin=0;
OPEN cursor12;
    cursor12_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor12 INTO vcodigo1;
        IF @fin=1 THEN
            LEAVE cursor12_loop;
        END IF;
        SET @co1=vcodigo1;
        OPEN cursor13;
            cursor13_loop: LOOP
                FETCH cursor13 INTO vcodigo2;
                IF @fin=1 THEN
                    LEAVE cursor13_loop;
                END IF;
                SET @co2=vcodigo2;
                OPEN cursor14;
                    FETCH cursor14 INTO vcodigo3;
                    IF @fin=1 THEN
                        LEAVE cursor14_loop;
                    END IF;
                    SET @co3=vcodigo3;

                       /* IF @co1=@co2=@co3 THEN
                            INSERT INTO TEMP6 VALUES(@co1);
                        END IF;*/ /*Here I try to compare the variables and it doesn't work*/
                    END LOOP cursor14_loop;
                CLOSE cursor14;
            END LOOP cursor13_loop;
        CLOSE cursor13;
    END LOOP cursor12_loop;
CLOSE cursor12;
END;$$
```

Comment: Show the code with loop block.

Comment: @temerariomalaga put your code to help you.

Comment: Sorry i forgot it. The code is just post

Comment: @temerariomalaga Your table `TEMP6` only has the field `@co1`?

Comment: TEMP6 only has codigo field. @co1 is the variable I try to insert into the table

Comment: @temerariomalaga The variables `@co1`,`@co2`,`@co3` have values​​? Because receive `vcodigo1`, `vcodigo2`, `vcodigo3`, but seem to have nothing.

Comment: @LucasHenrique The variables `@co1, @co2 and @co3` receive the values of vcodigo and vcodigo is a variable for select codigo in TEMP3, TEMP4 and TEMP5